# Compile Android project from the command line as if it was the first time, everytime?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When compiling my project from the command line I get to see the beauty of caching in action, a lot of tasks are skipped -- which is really good -- but in my case Im trying to test and find out whats slowing down my build; so **how can I compile the project from the command line as if it was the first time**, **everytime**?

Comment: Delete intermediary files before running the build.

Comment: @Shark Possible to do via the command line? I have quite a few modules.

Comment: Yes. For every of those `quite a few modules` you do `cd moduleX; rm -rf build/intermediates` and that will force a clean-build.

Comment: @Shark Thanks, Ill still keep the question open though as Im looking for a way to do all of this in one go.

Comment: Fair enough, but be prepared to end up with a bash script you'll execute every time (to clean up) before running the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want gradle to ignore `up-to-date` status of tasks, run with

```
--rerun-tasks
```

If you also want to re-download all dependencies, add

```
--refresh-dependencies
```

Quick side note: when gradle skips tasks because it's outputs are already up to date, it isn't exactly *caching*, but gradle's incremental builds feature in action.